# How can I get back-key press or Long press event in WearOs when my app is in background?

Tags: android, wear-os

I'm developing a wearOs application, Where I have a feature, app will do something when user long press on physical back-key even my app is background.
Currently I'm stuck there. I get the event when my app is foreground but I also want this event when the app is in background.

I used this code to get the event:

```
override fun onKeyLongPress(keyCode: Int, event: KeyEvent?): Boolean {
    if ( keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)
    {
        // Do something
    }
    return super.onKeyLongPress(keyCode, event)
}
```

Now my question is there any way to get this or any work-around there ??

Comment: If your app is backgrounded that key will probably go to a different process like the launcher/sysui.

Comment: @YuriSchimke Thanks for your comment. Could you please give some details how can I handle my scenario and learn more about this issue.

Comment: My point was that I don't think you can.  The physical buttons particularly are at the mercy of the OEM (Samsung) etc first before they get to the App.  I don't believe you can change the Suunto 7 button which launches the Suunto Maps app, but I'm not an expert.

Comment: Thanks @YuriSchimke ! I got your point. I think this answer will help others who will face the same issue